# Removing hashtags , hyperlinks and twitter handles from dataset in R using gsub

Tags: r, regex

I have searched but im not getting anywhere, probably because I'm very new to R and not understanding (and getting intimidated) how the logic/syntax for pattern matching and replacement with regex works. So I'd hope someone can help me with the specific code I need in R for removing hashtags (for example, `#trump`), removing hyperlinks (for example `pic.twitter.com/xxxx`) and removing twitter handles (for example `@xxxx`).

I have to use `gsub`.

For example, I have a few tweets like this:

**Input**

```
x <- c("\"If you like your doctor, you can keep your doctor.\" - #Obama 
#GunControl #GunControlNow pic.twitter.com/JpLpkj2LHB I don't know if
{Michelle #Obama} noticed, but I am not White & I am Not Male.
pic.twitter.com/TPplBj8ovg . @Eminem being honored by #Obama for his
rap battle win against @POTUS pic.twitter.com/YaYIuYWGlc")
```

**Desired output**

```
"\"If you like your doctor, you can keep your doctor.\" -  I don't know
if {Michelle } noticed, but I am not White & I am Not Male.  being
honored by for his rap battle win against"
```

Comment: Removing hashtags using `sub` is fairly easy.  Identifying and removing _any_ type of possible URL is _not_ easy, and in fact is a can of worms ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)).  The regex to match a general URL is quite lengthy, and is really what you should be using, assuming you want to do this with regex.

Comment: please could you share the sub code? for hyperlinks all i need deleted is "pic.twitter.com/xxxx" .. i could just use gsub ? does regex go along with gsub ? sorry a real R noob here !

Comment: If you are a noob that is pretty fine but without searching and coming with a detailed question, this is not pretty fine.

Comment: i did search ! now have some code obamaclean <- str_replace_all(tweets_obama, "#[a-z,A-Z]*","")
obamaclean <- str_replace_all(obamaclean,"@[a-z,A-Z]*", "")
obamacleaned <- str_replace_all(obamaclean,"pic.twitter.com/[a-z,A-Z,0-9]*","")

#removing hashtags , twitter hyperlinks and twitter handles from tweets_trump
trumpclean <- str_replace_all(tweets_trump, "#[a-z,A-Z]*","")
trumpclean <- str_replace_all(trumpclean,"@[a-z,A-Z]*", "")
trumpcleaned <- str_replace_all(trumpclean,"pic.twitter.com/[a-z,A-Z,0-9]*","")

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution which seems to be working (see below for caveats):

```
# x is your input text
gsub("#[A-Za-z0-9]+|@[A-Za-z0-9]+|\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)*/\\S+", "", x)

[1] "\"If you like your doctor, you can keep your doctor.\" -
    I don't know if {Michelle } noticed, but I am not White & I am Not Male.  .
    being honored by  for his rap battle win against  "
```

Note that this assumes that your URLs would always be of the form `pic.twitter.com/TPplBj8ovg`.  That is, there would one or more domain components, one item in the path, and no leading protocol.  In general, to match any URL, we would have to use a much more complicated pattern.

Comment: thanks Tim! i upvoted but since my reputation is zero i dont know whether it counts..also i cannot for the life of me figure out " |\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)*/\\S+" kindly shed some light on this part of the pattern..

Comment: I would recommend playing around with that part of the pattern in a demo tool, such as www.regex101.com.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter provides a [set of libraries](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text) for working with tweet text. There is a reason for it since *entities* (the idiomatic term for the non-textual components of a tweet as specified by Twitter) are pretty "ugh" and Twitter hashtags have some esoteric rules and URLs are also kinda "ugh" to regex away. Plus there are infrequently used "cashtags" ($XYZ) for stock quotes.

Unfortunately, Twitter does not have an R library, Python library or proper C[++] library, but we can use `rJava` for this:

```
library(rJava)
```

Gather dependencies:

```
c(
  "http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/twitter/twittertext/twitter-text/2.0.10/twitter-text-2.0.10.jar", 
  "http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.9.1/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.9.1.jar",
  "http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.7/jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar",
  "http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.1/jackson-core-2.8.1.jar",
  "http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.1/jackson-annotations-2.8.1.jar"
) -> deps

# download if necessary
if (!file.exists(deps[1])) { # assume we need them all if one is missing
  download.file(deps, basename(deps))
}
```

Init JVM

```
.jinit(force.init = TRUE)
```

Add dependent classes:

```
for (cp in basename(deps)) .jaddClassPath(cp)
```

Your sample data:

```
tweet <- ("\"If you like your doctor, you can keep your doctor.\" - #Obama 
#GunControl #GunControlNow pic.twitter.com/JpLpkj2LHB I don't know if
{Michelle #Obama} noticed, but I am not White & I am Not Male.
pic.twitter.com/TPplBj8ovg . @Eminem being honored by #Obama for his
rap battle win against @POTUS pic.twitter.com/YaYIuYWGlc")
```

Make the Java extractor function usable from R:

```
extractor <- new(J("com.twitter.twittertext.Extractor"))
```

We're eventually going to want to iterate over the start/end indices for all the identified entities so extract them all and make them something we can iterate over in R:

```
entities <- extractor$extractEntitiesWithIndices(tweet)$toArray()
```

Since we're working with indices of the entities we'll need a vector of the length of the tweet to create markers for extraction, defaulting to extracting all of them:

```
to_extract <- rep(TRUE, nchar(tweet))
```

Negate index ranges of the found entities:

```
for (i in seq_along(entities)) {
  to_extract[entities[[i]]$getStart():entities[[i]]$getEnd()] <- FALSE
}
```

Now, remove them (this character manipulation is not a strong point of R)

```
cat(paste0(strsplit(tweet, "")[[1]][to_extract], collapse=""))
## "If you like your doctor, you can keep your doctor." -  I don't know if
## {Michelle} noticed, but I am not White & I am Not Male. . being honored by for his
## rap battle win against
```

If you're new to R then ^^ is likely not the path for you. If you're on a crippled, legacy operating system like Windows where getting Java to work with R is not exactly unfraught with peril, ^^ is likely not the path for you.

However, naive regex-ing will likely end up mangling as well as extracting.